# New MVC 4 project based off ASP.net web forum application that uses Subsonic as ORM...where to start....?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orm, webforms, subsonic

I have been given the task of trying to convert our company's existing ASP.NET Web Forms application into an MVC 4 application (as an R&D starting project).  I have a little experience with MVC 2, but my issue is trying to actually get started.  We have existing stored procedures that we access via Subsonic as our ORM (so that they can be called in our code).  We also have a Data Access Layer that is tied in with Subsonic.

I know this is kind of a vauge question, but is there a known way I can use our existing stored procs and tables with a different ORM (such as NHibernate or something) to start creating this MVC application?

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason that the SP's need to change just because the ORM changes; you may want to to improve some of what you are doing and rewrite some of them, but not because the ORM changed.

Comment: E.J. Brennan  Thanks for your response.  I am almost at the point to where I want to just start from scratch, and generate new tables with CodeFirst based off my classes, but I was hoping there was a different approach so that I wouldn't have to omit our existing work.  For example, I am attempting to re-write a page that simply displays a list of existing contacts inside a gridview by searching for them.  A btn_click method gets called, that goes to a class called Contact, which contains a DataTable method that gets the data via SubSonic ExecuteDataSet().  How would I attempt this in MVC?